# Poisson distribution phone calls

Tags: probability

In a call center the number of received calls in a day can be modeled by a Poisson random variable. We know that on average about 0.5% of the time the call center receives no calls at all. How can I find the distribution of the number of received calls in a day?

Comment: What does the $0.5\%$ tell you in terms of the Poisson distribution?

Comment: Do you know the Possion pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of received calls in a day, i.e. $X\sim Pois(\lambda)$.

$P(X=0)=e^{-\lambda} = 1/200 \Rightarrow \lambda = \ln(200)$. Our number of calls in a day is distributed $Pois(\ln(200))$.